# How to manipulate SOAP web service's protocol for simulating damage?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, protocols

For a scientific homework, I need to manipulate the protocol which is built and sent by the framework for SOAP web services (in Java). The concrete task is to mapinuplate the protocol (simulating being damaged) before sending it.

I already have a working little web service. But I have no clue where a hook for manupulationg the protcol could be. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance
Jana

Comment: You may try intercepting the SOAP message using WireShark or any other network monitoring utility, damage it manually and transmit to endpoint. I did interception and transmission of SOAP messages from network, a long time back. You may tweak the process to damage the SOAP request.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. But AFAIK WireShark only displays things happening in the network, not enabeling manipulation... It's not enough to stop and forward a protocol, I'd have to go into the protocol code. And I think if this program would be able to do this it would be prohibited. ;-)

Comment: I understand. I am not very sure about this, but I guess given the kind of parity checking and other safety protocols implemented at the basic level of TCP/IP, it would be very difficult to partially damage the data packet. What you could easily do is garble the data inside the SOAP request. It would be nice if someone else could answer this question. I am equally curious to know if this is possible.

Comment: Do you mean garbelling the data before building the SOAP request or garbelling the whole SOAP request after it is built? The latter would definitely do for me... It has to be a "damaged protocol" not only "damaged data in a correct protocol". If I can't find a way I have to skip this for my work, but it would be a shame... That's why I also hope that someone has done some alternation to an already built protocol before (and will answer here).

Comment: Yeh, I meant "damaged data in a correct protocol". As for correct data in damaged protocol, I'm clueless. That's why I hope some else answers this for you.